# Displaying 4 textures using for loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm creating a game using `Swift 2.0` and `Sprite-Kit` with `Xcode7`. I want to implement 4 purple balls that are suppose to resemble lives. So every time the player gets hit he loses one purple ball. They are supposed to appear side by side. I was wondering if instead of hardcoding 4 balls on to the scene I could instead use a `for loop` to display 4 balls.

```
let purpleBall = SKSpriteNode(texture: purpleTexture)
purpleBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.65, self.frame.size.height * 0.92)
self.addChild(purpleBall)
```

I haven't been successful on getting 4 balls to appear on the scene. This was one of my attempts.

```
for(var i = 0.50; i <= 0.90; i = i + 0.10) {
        let purpleBall = SKSpriteNode(texture: purpleTexture)
        purpleBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * i, self.frame.size.height * 0.92)
        self.addChild(purpleBall)
}
```

Here I get an error: Binary operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGFloat' and 'Double'
Do I have to convert `i` to CGFloat? and will this code actually place 4 different balls side by side or only move the single one to each new position.

Comment: "Do I have to convert i to CGFloat?" Yes. You can't just try it? You have to take up Stack Overflow bandwidth with it first? "and will this code actually place 4 different balls side by side or only move the single one to each new position" Same question. Why don't you try it and see? You will get nowhere as a programmer behaving so gormlessly. A programmer *tries stuff*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an off by one error in the for loop. It should be a less than sign rather than less than or equal too. Your current code is going to create *five* purple balls.

You shouldn't really let i equal anything but an integer it's confusing. You could rewrite the code like this and it would do the same thing, without the worry of the float/double errors you're currently getting. Note that I will also use a constant called maxBalls, and distanceBetweenBalls so that you can easily change the number of balls and the distance without any complicated rewriting:

```
let maxBalls = 4
for(var i = 0; i < maxBalls; i++) {
    let purpleBall = SKSpriteNode(texture: purpleTexture)
    let ballXPosition = .50 + (i * .1)
    purpleBall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * ballXPosition, self.frame.size.height * 0.92)
    self.addChild(purpleBall)
```

This should avoid the issues you were facing before, hope that helps.

Comment: I made and edit. `i` has a value of int but .1 is a double. I got an error and the solution was to make `maxBalls`, `ballXPosition` and `i` a CGFloat